# C Program - Scanning in a String using scanf but reading from .txt file

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I have an assignment to create a .txt file with the sentence

```
 "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

I named it `pangram.txt` and was instructed to scan it in after gcc -o ... by using:

```
myprogram_bin < pangram.txt
```

However, I am trying to find the number of occurrences of the letter `'e'` and `'x'`. My program returns the correct number for `'e'` but returns `'x'` 5 times. I have to have it return the statement "The character _ has been found." every time the character entered as input is found. I'm not sure if it's my loop or if I need to use something like const char *pangram to call my srting. Any help on how to correct my issue and have it scan in the file using standard input (cannot read in a file in my code), would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void  problem_01_function(char char_to_find);

int main(){

    problem_01_function('e');
    problem_01_function('x');
    return 0;

}

void problem_01_function(char char_to_find){


    char pangram[50];
    scanf("%s", &pangram);
    int count_char_occur = 0;
    for(; count_char_occur < strlen(pangram);count_char_occur++)
    {
            if(pangram[count_char_occur] = char_to_find)
            {
                    printf("The character %c has been found. \n", char_to_find);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to use `==` on this line: `if(pangram[count_char_occur] = char_to_find)`

Comment: need `rewind(stdin);`

Comment: Using re-directed input as in `myprogram_bin < pangram.txt` is _not_ having the program read a .txt file.  The program is still reading from `stdin`.  The end effect of using `<` is similar for the first pass but code does not get to rewind `stdin` in general.  Change code to read from a `FILE*` opened via `fopen(pangram.txt,...)`.

Comment: You get the 'correct' answer for `e` by coincidence; the `scanf()` reads the word `The` and the faulty comparison counts each character in the string. The second call to `scanf()` reads `quick` and then counts 5 characters. You need to think about reading the whole line at once and scanning that.  Either do this first and then scan the string for the character you're looking for, or rewind the file between letters.  Generally, reading from a file is slow so you try to avoid reading a file more than once. Also note that you cannot usefully rewind standard input if the input is the terminal.

Comment: @chux: sorta...it is reading a text file; this standard input is seekable and rewindable, unlike terminal or pipe input.  You're right that you often can't rewind standard input, but you can't rewind every file that you open, either (for example, `/dev/tty` is not rewindable either).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler So redirected input as in `myprogram_bin < pangram.txt` is universally `rewind()`-able?  LSNED.  How does `myprogram_bin` know if its `stdin` is from a rewindable source?  Maybe that is a question to post?

Comment: @chux: if stdin is a regular file, it's rewindable because seekability is a property of the type of file the descriptor is accessing. A few other device types are rewindable (block specials, character specials for disks) but the majority are not (pipes, FIFOs, sockets, ttys, ...). How to find out whether a file is seekable? Either `fstat(0)` and detect the file type, or try the seek and look for error conditions. The 'easier to ask forgiveness than permission' approach is simplest -- and ultimately most reliable. Distinguishing between a character disk device and a tty is tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you are going to scan the whole string

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

with only 1 scanf()

then you do not have to use "%s" . You have to use other format:

```
scanf("%49[^.]", &pangram);
```

2)
The comparison:

```
if(pangram[count_char_occur] = char_to_find)
```

should be

```
if(pangram[count_char_occur] == char_to_find)
```

3) You can use [`fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) instead of `scanf()`. this will avoid to call yoour program with `< pangram.txt` option

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 completely solved my problem! Since I have to use scanf for the assignment, part 3 does not apply since I cannot use fscanf. Thanks MOHAMED!

Comment: Instead of `scanf`, using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)`(stdin, pangram, sizeof pangram)` is somewhat more elegant, and easier to maintain if you change the size of `pangram`, or if you end up opening a file with `fopen` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void  problem_01_function(char char_to_find);

int main(){
    problem_01_function('e');
    rewind(stdin);
    problem_01_function('x');
    return 0;
}

void problem_01_function(char char_to_find){
    int ch;
    while((ch = fgetc(stdin))!=EOF){
        if(ch == char_to_find)
            printf("The character %c has been found. \n", char_to_find);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `rewind()` do the same as what `open(readme, O_RDONLY);` `read(fd, read_buff, 50);` would do?

Comment: @WedaPashi File is passed to the program by a redirect.

Comment: Well, then it makes `rewind()` more efficient, doesn't it?

Comment: @WedaPashi I think that it does not change much.

Comment: stdin does not work if the console is not a redirect to a file, but the program does not work and in any case that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * readme = "/Desktop/readme.txt";

void  problem_01_function(char char_to_find);

int main()
{
    problem_01_function('e');
    problem_01_function('x');
    return 0;
}

void problem_01_function(char char_to_find)
{
    int fd = 0 , count_char_occur = 0;
    char read_buff[50];
    fd = open(readme, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, read_buff, 50);
    for(count_char_occur = 0; count_char_occur < strlen(read_buff); count_char_occur++)
    {
        if(read_buff[count_char_occur] = char_to_find)
        {
                printf("The character %c has been found. \n", char_to_find);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - Sorry, I misread - if you're not allowed to read from  a file, then modify the `fgets` line to read from `stdin` instead of `pfile`, and omit all `fopen`, `fclose` stuff.

```
void read_in_string_stdin (char pangram[]){
  printf("please enter the pangram\n");
  if (fgets(pangram, 50, stdin) == NULL) {
/* stuff */
}
```

and to compile and run:

```
gcc -Wall -o zpg pangram.c 
./zpg < pangram_file.txt
```

---

For reading in from a file, you'll want to open a file using [`fopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html), read with either [`fscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) or [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), check the return value, and close the file with [`fclose`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html).

- If you use `fscanf` with the `%s` string, it will stop at the first whitespace encountered - hence use of the `%[^.]` or `%[^\n]` formatting flags instead, to read until the first period or newline, respectively.
- If you use `fgets`, it will read until a newline or a limiting number of characters have been read.

Also, you do have an assignment vs. equality-testing problem in the `if` loop.

---

Stylistically, there are also several issues (not error-producing on the computer's part, but error-prone for the reader) around the naming of variables and functions.

- Name functions by what they do, not by metadata such as problem number.
- The `count_char_occur` variable above is misleading, since it doesn't count occurrences of the sought char.
- It's best to keep `for`-loop conditions as self-contained as possible, in case of later copy/paste (e.g. "I've pasted this elsewhere and ... what was the initial condition again??")

Here's a working and prettified version:

```
 void count_occurrences(char char_to_find) {
   /* Problem 01 function. */

   char pangram[50];
   FILE *pfile = fopen("pangram_file.txt", "r"); /* Opens in read-only mode. */                                                                               

   if (pfile == NULL) {
     printf("could not open file.  Exiting now.\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (fgets(pangram, 50, pfile) == NULL) {
     printf("could not read string from  file.  Exiting now.\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   fclose(pfile);
   printf("Now I have string |%s|\n", pangram);  /* Check that you have what you think */

   int string_pos; // "count_char_occur" was a misleading variable name
   int occurrences_found = 0;
   for (string_pos = 0; string_pos < strlen(pangram);string_pos++) { 
     if(pangram[string_pos] == char_to_find) { /* --- Assignment vs. Equality --- */
       printf("The character %c has been found, at position %i. \n", pangram[string_pos], string_pos);
       occurrences_found++;
     }
   }

/* Keep the user in the loop about what happened - reduce assumptions! */
   if (occurrences_found == 0)
     printf("The character %c was not found.\n\n", char_to_find);
   else
     printf("The character %c was found %i times in total.\n\n", char_to_find, occurrences_found);
 }
```

---

Now that you see this, this guy has a lot of responsibility, and it makes more sense to delegate one duty per function, doesn't it?  Have one function handle the reading-in of the string, and another to count occurrences.  Then you also **aren't repeating the work** of reading in the string for every different char you want to count in the same string.

```
void read_in_string (char pangram[]){        
  FILE *pfile = fopen("pangram_file.txt", "r");
  /* .... intervening lines as in above .... */
  printf("Now I have string |%s|\n", pangram);
}

void count_occurrences_only (char mystring[], char char_to_find) {
  int string_pos;
  /* .... intervening lines as in above, through end of count_occurrences .... */
}

int main(void) {
  char pangram[50];
  read_in_string(pangram);

  count_occurrences_only(pangram, 'e');
  count_occurrences_only(pangram, 'x');

  return 0;
}
```